# Gets older or Got older?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

Is "I love her more when she got older." correct or "I love her more when she gets older."

Comment: Neither makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It would either be 'I love**d** her more when she got older' or 'I love her more **as** she gets older'.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the meaning is subtly different between those two sentences.  The first one makes it sound like the speaker **preferred** her when she was older: it's like saying "I didn't love you as much when you were younger",  which sounds unkind.   In the second one it sounds like the speaker is saying that his or her **love continued to grow as she got older**, which sounds like he loved her when she was younger too.   I suspect that the questioner should use option 2.